# VSCode: Mouse pointer, caret, and grabber not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I switched from Arch to Debian. On Debian the mouse in VSCode is acting differently and I can't find the setting to change to fix the problem.

The mouse remains a pointer all the time. It doesn't change to a caret when hovering over text or selecting/highlighting text, and it doesn't change to a grabber when hovering over resizable panels like the file explorer or terminal.

I've been searching through settings.json and I've been googling but I can't figure out what setting to change to make it act normal. Like it does in every other program on my computer.

For reference:

Pointer (stuck as this all the time)

[image]

Caret (should turn to caret when over select-able text)

[image]

Grabber (should turn to grabber when over resizable panels)

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a setting for that... it should "just work". Have you tried reinstalling VSC?

Comment: Or even, have you tried restarting the computer? Or at least logging out and back in?

Comment: Yes I've restarted and reinstalled, didn't help.

Comment: do you observe similar behaviour in other electron apps such as discord?